# Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost:8084

Tags: java, firefox, tomcat, netbeans

I am trying to run my web application from Netbeans 8.0.1 using Apache Tomcat 7.0.56 and once I submit my login form I keep getting the following error:

> ```
> Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost:8084.
>
>  - The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
>  - If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
>  - If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.
> ```

My other applications work fine it just seems to be this one. I don't have a clue why this is happening.

Can anyone figure out what's going wrong?

Here is my Apache Tomcat log:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.56"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.56"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
Listening for transport dt_shmem at address: tomcat_shared_memory_id
Dec 11, 2014 1:49:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.31 using APR version 1.4.8.
Dec 11, 2014 1:49:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
Dec 11, 2014 1:49:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.1h 5 Jun 2014)
Dec 11, 2014 1:49:15 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Dec 11, 2014 1:49:15 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Dec 11, 2014 1:49:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2409 ms
Dec 11, 2014 1:49:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Dec 11, 2014 1:49:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.56
Dec 11, 2014 1:49:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\conf\Catalina\localhost\coursework.xml
Dec 11, 2014 1:49:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deployment of configuration descriptor C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\conf\Catalina\localhost\coursework.xml has finished in 1,706 ms
Dec 11, 2014 1:49:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\webapps\docs
Dec 11, 2014 1:49:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\webapps\docs has finished in 265 ms
Dec 11, 2014 1:49:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\webapps\examples
Dec 11, 2014 1:49:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\webapps\examples has finished in 759 ms
Dec 11, 2014 1:49:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\webapps\host-manager
Dec 11, 2014 1:49:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\webapps\host-manager has finished in 231 ms
Dec 11, 2014 1:49:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\webapps\manager
Dec 11, 2014 1:49:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\webapps\manager has finished in 292 ms
Dec 11, 2014 1:49:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\webapps\ROOT
Dec 11, 2014 1:49:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\webapps\ROOT has finished in 196 ms
Dec 11, 2014 1:49:18 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Dec 11, 2014 1:49:18 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Dec 11, 2014 1:49:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3599 ms
Dec 11, 2014 1:49:19 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor process
INFO: Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
Dec 11, 2014 1:49:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig undeploy
INFO: Undeploying context [/coursework]
Dec 11, 2014 1:49:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\conf\Catalina\localhost\coursework.xml
Dec 11, 2014 1:49:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deployment of configuration descriptor C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\conf\Catalina\localhost\coursework.xml has finished in 554 ms
Dec 11, 2014 1:49:22 PM org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase start
INFO: The start() method was called on component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/coursework]] after start() had already been called. The second call will be ignored.
```

Comment: did you try to open it from another browser ?

Comment: @mehdizahrane Yes, checked with IE and Chrome, same problem occurs

Comment: You are using the wrong port:  Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]. Try localhost:8080

Comment: @Stefan This is the url I am using in browser: `http://localhost:8084/coursework/do/login`

Comment: @user3574492 what about `http://localhost:8080/coursework/do/login`?

Comment: Yes, `http://localhost:8080/coursework/do/login` works fine, but now for some reason when I add a few watches to my variables and debug my program the values of the variables don't show up in debug mode. The actual program logic works fine however. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Try to avoid that the server is running in multiple instances, each with a new port. Shutdown all unnecessary. At deploy the information that a new instance is created show you the next new port. The first server starts with port 8080 then incremented by 1. The port 8084 shows that running 5 instances. Where now to pick the debug values? Netbeans : go to server tab and shutdown all servers , end and restart debugging again.